# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: html, css, json, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to learn react redux api call
- so I took an example and implemented in stackblitz but I am getting the below error when I select some channel and hit top news button
- can you tell me how to fix it
- providing my code and stackblitz below
  https://medium.com/@lavitr01051977/basic-react-redux-app-with-async-call-to-api-e478e6e0c48b

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-realworld-j95tpu?file=actions/index.js

```
code
export function fetchPosts(channel) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPosts());
    return fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=${channel}&apiKey=${MY_API_KEY}`)
      .then(response => response.json(),
      error => console.log('An error occurred.', error),
    )
      .then((json) => {
        dispatch(receivedPosts(json));
      }, );
  };
}

error

VM1672:37 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `TopNews`.
    in TopNews (created by Connect(TopNews))
    in Connect(TopNews) (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
    in Provider


Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `TopNews`.
    at invariant (invariant.js:42)
    at instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js:74)
    at instantiateChild (ReactChildReconciler.js:44)
    at eval (ReactChildReconciler.js:71)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:77)
    at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js:172)
    at Object.instantiateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:70)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:185)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:224)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:703)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is an import/export syntax issue.  I'll walk you through how to find it.

The problem's real location is shown by the component stack trace:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `TopNews`.
    in TopNews (created by Connect(TopNews))
    in Connect(TopNews) (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
    in Provider
```

If we look in `TopNews.js`, it only renders `<h3>`, `<div>`, and `<NewsItem>`.  `h3` and `div` are just basic tags, so it's probably `NewsItem` that's the problem.

At the top of `TopNews.js`, you have:

```
import { NewsItem } from '../components/NewsItem';
```

However, in `NewsItem.js`, you have:

```
export default NewsItem ;
```

So, you're doing a default export, but a named import, and so `NewsItem` is undefined in `TopNews.js`.

Try changing it to be `import NewsItem from "../components/NewsItem"` and it should work.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how come removing the curly brackets fixed it...it would be great if you explain so that in future I will fix it myself

Comment: Using curly braces makes it a _named_ import.  Without curly braces, it's a _default_ import.  In your code, you wrote `export default NewsItem`, so you used a _default export_. You need to use the same kind of import/export on both sides.  For some more info, see [this quick summary of ES6 module syntax](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6#modules), [a more detailed article on ES6 modules](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-modules-in-depth) , and [this list of other posts on ES6 features](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/es6-features.md).